# Previous/Next jQuery effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've been trying to create an effect for a previous/next effect [that I saw at this website](http://na.square-enix.com/ffxiii-2/#/media) but can't achieve it correctly and would like to know if someone can help me please.

[Here it's mine so that you can inspect it and see the code](http://www.freewaymotors.com.ar/prueba/index.html), it's not working fine in Firefox and only it's you pass the mouse quickly it flickers and works really bad.
I would like to achieve the same effect as in the website of Final Fantasy.

I've tried also using jQuery UI hide and show but couldn't make it run correctly at Firefox and Opera either.

Since I'm only trying to achieve the effect correctly I don't have an hover state, only inverted the arrow when using `mouseenter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it for Previous button in previousNextSlider.js:

```
//Previous
$('.bx-prev').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).removeClass(".js-opened").stop().animate({
        'margin-left': '-87px'
        }, {
        duration: 300,
        complete: function(){
            $(this).css({
                'background-image' : 'url(images/nextSliderButton.png)'
            }).addClass(".js-opened").stop().animate({
                'margin-left' : 0
            }, {duration: 100});
        }
    });
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass(".js-opened"))
        $(this).stop().animate({
            'margin-left': '-87px'
            }, {
            duration: 100,
            complete: function(){
                $(this).css({
                    'background-image' : 'url(images/previousSliderButton.png)'
                }).removeClass(".js-opened").stop().animate({
                    'margin-left' : 0
                }, {duration: 300});
            }
        });
    else
        $(this).stop().animate({
            'margin-left': 0
            }, {duration: 300});
});
```

just tried and it works perfect fixing "quick mouse move" issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot John! It's working as I was expecting to. I have only one problem and is that it's not working on Firefox (v18.0.1) for Mac, it's like bugged and as soon as you enter the mouse it's like activating both states (mouseenter and mouseleave).

Comment: Try to use Dimitri's tip and mine together to add unanimated wrap which will fire `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events and a span which will make all animation stuff.  You can edit `appendControls` function in `bxslider.js` and add some styles for new spans.

Comment: I've done that and it's working perfect! Thanks again to both for your very useful help and taking the time to help me, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry for bothering again John but I can't make a last correction. Every time you pass the cursor for example over Previous and then quickly over Next it activates this last one leaving it with the hover state. I changed the jQuery script a little, can you please help me with this last thing? Thanks!

Comment: Arbusto, can you reproduce a bug? Animation doesn't work on your link at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding span inside each *< a >*.

Add mouseEnter to your  and make it animate your span. The images/background should be inside the span.

Something like this (untested):

```
$('a').on('mouseEnter', function () {
    $(this).find('span').animate({
        //Animation stuff
    });
});
```

ps: I appreciate if you avoid hotlinking.

Comment: Hi Dimitri, thanks for your reply. I've done that and now it's working right on every browser. What I can't do is that when you go with the mouse quickly in and out to stop and go back instead of continuing with the animation, tried with stop but I'm doing it wrong. Where should I use it?

Comment: I see you have solved the issue. Please +1 John Miller and mine answers.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I've tried to do it before but it says I need a reputation of 15 to do it, sorry.